# Javascript get key of nested JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json response that looks like the image below. I want to get all dates from the json and store in an array.

```
  function buyOption(){
      var ticker = document.getElementById('ticker').value;

    fetch("https://stock-and-options-trading-data-provider.p.rapidapi.com/options/JPM", {
    
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dataset = data;
      console.log(dataset['options'])
      loadTable()
      
    })

    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });


    function loadTable(){
      expiration_dates = []
      dates = dataset['options']
      // console.log(JSON.parse(dates))
      
      var keys = [];
        for(var k in dates) keys.push(k);
      console.log(keys)// returns ["0","1","2",3","5",6","9","10","11"]
  
      console.log(dates[0].value) // returns undefined 
      
    }


}
```

[image]

goal is to have expiration_dates = ["2020-08-21","2020-08-28"]

Comment: Can you add the actual `JSON` response you get from that API in the question please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. This will give you only the `expiration dates`.

```js
var obj = {
  "options": [{
    "10-2-2001": "",
    "someOtherProp": ""
  }, {
    "20-2-2001": "",
    "someOtherProp": ""
  }]
}

var expDates = obj.options.map(o=>Object.keys(o)[0])

console.log(expDates)
```

Refs:

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

A simple array map  should do the trick and use Object.keys() array to get first key from each object in your data array

```js
const dates = dataset['options'].map(o => Object.keys(o)[0])

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script>
const dataset = {
    options: [{
      '2013-12-22': {
        puts: [],
        calls: []
      }},
      {'2013-02-15': {
        puts: [],
        calls: []
      }},
     { '2018-01-01': {
        puts: [],
        calls: []
      }}
    ]

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let result = dataSet.options.map(x => Object.keys(x));
console.log(result.flat(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const options=dates.options.map(o=>
  Object.keys(o).filter(k=>k.match(/^2\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/))[0]);
```

The idea is to loop over all options, get all keys for each of the objects and filter out the keys matching the Regexp, which is a date format, starting with `2`. From the filtered keys-array I am only interested in the first element (`[0]`).

Answer (score -1):

```
for(k in dates) {
    keys.push((v=>{
        for(let i in v) return i;
    })(dates[k]));
}
```

Try it